# ImageMagick failed to convert colors in PDF

Tags: pdf, colors, imagemagick

I have got a PDF document containing a red font which I want to replace by a black font.

I tried the following command according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/202978/137286):

```
convert -density 300 doc.pdf -fill black -opaque "#e1342d" -fuzz 60% output.pdf
```

I received the specific color by selecting a pixel's color from the following screenshot I took:

[image: Screenshot of my document's font color]
([→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8TzJ/show/) containing the original image)

Unfortunately, the document is still the same after converting. I think I misused the `-fuzz` parameter.

> The distance can be in absolute intensity units or, by appending % as
>   a percentage of the maximum possible intensity (255, 65535, or
>   4294967295).
>   
>   — [ImageMagick command-line documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz)

I've tried 0%, 10%, 20%, ... 100%, but none worked.

---

I wanted to verify that Imagick actually loads and converts the PDF:

```
convert -density 300 doc.pdf -fill black +opaque red output.pdf
```

Funnily enough, this outputs a completely white PDF (note that the page count was preserved).

The command below outputs a completely yellow PDF.

```
convert -density 300 doc.pdf -fill blue +opaque blue output.pdf
```

**My system:**

- Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit
- ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-09-10 Q16
- Ghostscript 9.10

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: @terdon I am sorry for not having included it. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved the correct result with a slightly different command:

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -fuzz 55% -fill black -opaque "#e1342d" out.pdf
```

tested on Windows with ImageMagick 6.4.4 2008-09-27 Q16

Comment: I've quickly created another test document using Office 2013 and #e1342 as the font color. Your command works perfectly with this file, but unfortunately not with my original document. Do you have any ideas as to why there may be differences?

Comment: **My solution:** I supposed some differences in the file format of my original PDF, therefore I tried converting it (the PDF) to another PDF (essentially rewriting) using http://online2pdf.com/. Converting the font color of the rewritten PDF with your command worked beautifully.