# how to print a black/grayscale pdf in some chosen color

Tags: pdf, printing

I have some PDFs that I want to print in a color instead of the grayscale/black&white color.

I see some questions/answers about removing color. But I want to change to some color. And I don't see any options to do so. The PDFs are created from an epson scanner device.

I want to do that on linux.

Comment: Whoever downvotes, please specify reason for that.

Comment: I found my question has been answered in another question but the other question was not generic enough to find so leaving my question to possibly catch searches: http://superuser.com/a/202978/111432

Comment: Here's an online tool that changes black and white to a color scheme of your choice: https://supertool.org/automatically-add-color-to-pdfs-to-print-without-black-ink/